# preferences getting lost after app has run for awhile

Tags: android, preferences, lifecycle

In my main activity I read some preferences

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
      fontSize = settings.getFloat("textsize", (float) 20);
      userName = settings.getString("userName","");
   }
```

In various other sub-activities I reference these variables like this

```
            body.setTextSize(Main.fontSize);
```

This works fine most of the time.  Occasionally after the app has been running for a while and I relaunch it, all the configuration variable appear to be empty. It is erratic and hard to reproduce when debugging.  When it happens, I can hit back repeatedly through all the old screens until it exits, then relaunch and the preferences are back and working

I could randomly try moving things around into different places like onStart(), or onRestart(), which hasn't helped so far. Or redo every activity to reread the shared preferences when it starts. but I'd prefer to understand what about the lifecycle I've gotten wrong that is causing this problem.

Comment: "I could randomly try moving things around into different places".  There's no randomness about it.  Android is destroying your activity, as documented.  Save preferences in onPause(), reload them in onResume().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android regularly destroys your Activity and recreates it when needed.
Therefore, your `onCreate()` function is reading the saved `SharedPreferences` values, but the class variables `fontSize` and `userName` are not staying in scope.

I believe that the problem seems *random* and is exasperated because these variables appear to be `static`. I say this because your example accesses `fontSize` in a static way:

```
body.setTextSize(Main.fontSize);
```

You should save the values whenever they are changed or in `onPause()`, as you probably already do. But, reading them only in `onCreate()` is not enough because Android is not always going to completely destroy your Activity. So, `onCreate()` will not be called every time your Activity resumes. You must re-read the values either whenever you need them, or in `onResume();`.

I wrote 'exasperated', above, because static variables are not automatically cleared by Java unless the class is completely destroyed. Therefore, sometimes the values will stick around longer than other times making the behavior look unpredictable.

---

Finally, it is not best practices to allow these values to be static. There are many other ways to share them between Activites, including SharedPreferences.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  I guess I'll just change the subactivities to reload the shared preferences.  It just seemed like a lot of overhead since it was mostly working this way.